# how to use sed for one word changing

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I trying to change one word from a file that consisting of:

=== the file that I want to change ./subscriptions ===

```
Drafts
INBOX
INBOX.&A5IDmQOfA6YDkQOhA5wDkQ-
INBOX.&A5IDmQOfA6YDkQOhA5wDkQ- &A58DmQOaA58DnQOfA5wDmQOaA58-
INBOX.&A5IDmQOfA6YDkQOhA5wDkQ- &A5MDoQORA6YDlQOZA58-
INBOX.&A5IDmQOfA6YDkQOhA5wDkQ- &A5UDkwOaA6EDmQOjA5c-
INBOX.&A5IDmQOfA6YDkQOhA5wDkQ- IT
INBOX.&A5QDlwOcA58DowOZA58Dow- &A6QDnwOcA5UDkQOj-
INBOX.&A5UDmgOYA5UDowOVA5kDow-
INBOX.&A5UDmgOYA5UDowOVA5kDow-.FORUM
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-.&A5gDkQOdA58DoAOfA6UDmwOfA6M-
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-.&A6MDmgOb- &A5oDkQOhA6QDlQOj- &A6MDmQOkA5kDowOXA6M-
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-.&A6MDmgOb- &A6QDpQOhA5k-
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-.&A6MDnwOlA5IDkQOkA5YDnwOTA5sDnwOl-
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-.AB &A5oDkQOhA6QDlQOj- &A6MDmQOkA5kDowOXA6M-
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-.AB &A5YDlQOhA5IDnwOl-
INBOX.&A6ADlQObA5EDpAOVA6M-.AB &A6QDlgOZA6kDoQOZA5QDnwOl-
```

I want to change only the INBOX word and not any of the INBOX.xxxxx
Looking at the sed command, I tried:

```
sed 's/INBOX[^.]/INBOX_old/g' ./subscriptions
```

But running it (at Ubuntu server 20.04) I got no any change at all. Modifying the command to:

```
sed 's/INBOX/INBOX_old/g' ./subscriptions
```

I change all the instances of INBOX even the INBOX.xxxxx

What I am doing wrong? Please help me.
Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: Prepend code with 4 leading spaces to format it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The `[^.]` **has to** match a not a dot character. So if you have a line like:

```
INBOX
     ^ END OF LINE! NO MORE CHARACTERS
```

It will *not* match such line, because there are no other character after `INBOX`, so regex will fail.

You can match a non-dot or end of line, with like:

```
sed 's/INBOX\([^.]\|$\)/INBOX_old\1/'
```

The `$` matches end of line, the `\([^.]\|$\)` matches a non-dot *or* end of line, and if a character other then dot was matched, then `\1` is substituted for it (so that `INBOXa` will result in `INBOX_olda` - ie. the character after INBOX is preserved).

That said, it looks like you want to substitute INBOX if it's the whole line, like:

```
sed 's/^INBOX$/INBOX_old/'
```

I recommend https://regexcrossword.com/ to learn regexes with fun.